# Change Image after Change in input

Tags: javascript, jquery

JSfiddle Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/ZfT64/1/

Whenever user inputs `image url` in `input` box, I would like to append them immediately in `img_logo` id of image section.

Not sure, about what `event` to work with.

Here is my Code :-

```
<input type="text" name="org_img" id="org_img" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="http://www.example.com/logo.png" value="<?php echo isset($row['org_img']) ? htmlentities($row['org_img']) :  'http://www.example.com/img/logo.png'; ?>" />

<span class="pull-right" id="img_logo"><img width="300px" height="80px" src="<?php echo isset($row['org_img']) ? htmlentities($row['org_img']) :  'http://www.example.com/img/logo.png'; ?>" /></span>
```

and below is Javascript function for validity and Appending in `img_logo` ID.

```
function IsValidImageUrl(url, callback) {
    jQuery("<img>", {
        src: url,
        error: function() { callback(1); },
        load: function() { callback(0); }
    });
}



jQuery('#org_img').change(function() {
    var img_name = jQuery('#org_img').val();
    IsValidImageUrl(img_name, function (val){
        if (val == 0)
            jQuery('#img_logo').html('<img src="'+img_name+'" width="300px" height="80px" />');
        if (val == 1)
            alert('Please Provide Valid URL Image');
            jQuery('#img_logo').html('<img src="http://www.example.com/img/logo.png" width="300px" height="80px" />');
    });
});
```

But this is not Working , Need Help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this

http://jsfiddle.net/ZfT64/4/

```
function IsValidImageUrl(url, callback) {
    jQuery("<img>", {
        src: url,
        error: function() { callback(1,null); },
        load: function() { callback(0,url); }
    });
}

$('#org_img').change(function() {
    var img_name = $(this).val();
    IsValidImageUrl(img_name, function (val,url){
        if (val == 0) {
            $('#image_logo').attr('src',url);
        }
        if (val == 1) {
            alert('Please Provide Valid URL Image');
            $('#image_logo').attr('src',"https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png");
        }
    });
});
```